# Hybrid drive: How does the system decide where files go, SSD vs. HDD, and can I change that?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hybrid-storage

I got a new laptop, my first with a hybrid drive. Only 128GB of SSD (which I was told is much faster than traditional hard drives) and nearly six times as much HDD. I've noticed that already well over half the SSD is taken up and I've barely downloaded/installed anything. I'm wondering what will happen as time goes by and I download stuff  (I usually download music and videos and also lots of PDF files, and I will need to install a few video editing and graphics editors for a course I'm planning to take).

My questions are:

1. How does the computer decide where things go, HDD, or SSD?
2. Can I change where things go (e.g., put some PDF files or a program I use often in the SSD)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, the SSD is used by the system as a form of cache.

Frequently used files & startup items will be copied to it by the OS/driver controller, in order to speed up repeating operations.

The user has no control over this functionality.
If you need full control, you will need to 'break' the fusion/hybrid drive into its individual components & set it up as two independent drives instead. I would avoid doing this, as the system will probably do a better job of it.

[Fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_Drive)/[hybrid drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive) were really a stop-gap until the prices of larger SSDs came down to reasonable levels.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you.  Btw, based on how much I paid, it seems to me the SSD prices still have not come down as much.

Comment: Well, my 1TB SSD cost me £450... you can now get them for under £100, so they have come down a lot; not to HD prices yet, but prices have reduced by a significant amount in the past few years. ;)

Comment: Wow, that's a big difference!